# Is it safe to run a single zookeeper instance?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Is it safe to run a single zookeeper instance?  I have one zookeeper server and 3 kafka brokers, which would make up my cluster.  I'd like Zookeeper to manage the the Kafka cluster.  My thinking is that once I'm up and running, I can add servers to the zookeeper cluster.  Is this doable/wise?

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe as you have a single point of failure for the entire cluster.

Production Kafka clusters have between 3 and 7 Zookeepers, depending on size of Zookeeper clients interacting with the cluster, as described in `Kafka: Definitive Guide` book